# Swift optionals - warning on conditional cast from 'x' to 'x' always succeeds

Tags: swift2, nsuserdefaults

I was wondering if there is a way to turn off/avoid 'yellow' warnings in xcode on `if let...NSUserDefaults` constructs where the key is of a known value.

For example:

```
if let x = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("myKey") as? Int {...}
```

Because of the `if let` I have to use `as?`. However, as I am using a known value type (in this case integer) the `as? Int` is effectively redundant - which is why I am getting the 'yellow warning'.

Thoughts? Is there a better way to code these types of constructs?

Comment: Instead of removing the warning, better remove the error... If you don't need  the conditional cast, then don't use it. :)

Comment: tried that. I get an actual error: 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type not Int'. Are you saying: do not use 'if let' just 'let' as I know the type?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying don't use `if let ... as? ...` with `.integerForKey` which does not, if I recall correctly, return an Optional (it returns 0 if the value doesn't exist) and does not need type casting.

Comment: Cool. You're welcome. I made a proper answer from my comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion would be to address the issue instead of silencing the warnings. :)

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("myKey")` does not return an Optional, and the type is known, so you don't need neither optional binding with `if let` nor type casting with `as?`.

Just this:

```
let x = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("myKey")
```

will suffice, since `.integerForKey` just returns `0` if it can't get the actual value.

If you don't like this behavior of getting a default value (I don't), then don't use `.integerForKey` and use `objectForKey` with optional binding and type casting instead. Like you were doing first but with `.objectForKey` replacing `.integerForKey`. That way you'll get an actual nil if the value for the key is unreachable, not a default value.

```
if let x = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults(). objectForKey("myKey") as? Int {...}
```

Comment: Ok. So the only issue I have with that is that 0 (or the default answer) could be a valid result in the context of the program/code. So I would say that if there is a need to test if a value has actually been set AND the default return value could be valid result in the context of the code, one should use the 'objectForKey' as? <type>. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check always the signature:
<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on the symbol `integerForKey:` or look at Quick Help.

You will see:

```
func integerForKey(_ defaultName: String) -> Int
```

It reveals the return value is a non optional.

Non optionals can retrieved directly as described in Eric's answer without any type casting, optional binding causes an error.

That's one of the essential semantics in Swift.